# How to speed up an insert transaction being repeated over and over

Tags: sql, insert

I have created 2 temp tables, `#Table1` being the source and `#Table2` being the output table. I have to traverse through each row on `#Table1` to make the necessary calculations before inserting each row into `#Table2` because the calculation is also dependent on previous rows in `#Table2`.

I have all the rows in the order I want, and have all the calculations working perfectly. The only problem is that when I go through my 30,000 rows of test data, it takes over 30 minutes. Which means when I expand the query to the full scope of over 2,000,000 rows it will take far too long.

**Example Tables:**

[image: Example Tables]

My solution on traversing through each record in `#Table1` to come up with `#Table2` is provided below.

```
exec [database_name].dbo.drop_if_exists '#Table2'
create table #Table2 (ID int, Shipment varchar(8), Delivery int, Arrival datetime, ETA datetime, ETA_TimeStamp datetime, Compliant int)

declare @z int
declare @currentShipment varchar(8)
declare @currentStop int
declare @previousID int
declare @previousETA datetime

set @z = 1
while @z <= (Select max(ID) from #Table1)
Begin
Set @currentShipment = (Select Shipment from #Table1 where ID = @z)
Set @currentStop  = (Select Delivery from #Table1 where ID = @z)
Set @previousID = (Select max(ID) from #Table2 where Shipment = @currentShipment AND Delivery = @currentStop AND ID < @Z AND Compliant = 1)
Set @previousETA = (Select ETA from #Table2 where ID = @previousID)

 if (Select count(Shipment) from #Table2 where Shipment = @currentShipment AND Delivery = @currentStop AND ID < @Z AND Compliant = 1) = 0
    BEGIN
    insert into #Table2 Select ID
    , Shipment
    , Delivery
    , Arrival
    , ETA
    , ETA_Timestamp
    , Compliant_Prelim as [Compliant]
    from #Table1
    where ID = @Z
    END

 if (Select count(Shipment) from #Table2 where Shipment = @currentShipment AND Delivery = @currentStop AND ID < @Z AND Compliant = 1) > 0
    BEGIN
    insert into #Table2 Select ID
    , Shipment
    , Delivery
    , Arrival
    , ETA
    , ETA_Timestamp
    , case when (Select Compliant_Prelim from #Table1 where ID = @z) = 1
        AND ETA_TimeStamp <= dateadd(hh, -1, @previousETA)
        then 1
        else 0 end as [Compliant]
    from #Table1
    where ID = @Z
    END
Set @z = @z + 1
End

Select * from #Table2
```

How do I speed up the insert statement given this example?

Comment: Your issue is the loop...SQL will never function well as a linear language, it's intended to be set based or 'all rows at once'.  Think of having a car and wanting to drive 10 miles (2 million records?).  Think of this loop as stopping every 2 feet to rebuild your car from the ground up while doing so...it's not very effective, in fact it's painfully slow.  Kill the loop, one script = 10 mile journey without stopping.

Comment: @Twelfth I personally agree with you, but I'm not aware of any other way to do the calculations necessary. If you can find a way to accomplish the same thing while killing the loop, feel free to suggest something else in an answer.

Comment: Definately doable...the two insert statements look identical except for the compliant column and could be turned into one statement with a case statement on the compliant line (change the if to a case statement when determining what to insert into the compliant column...that alone should shorten the run time on this).  The logic in @previous ETA is probably the most challenging part.  What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance isn't in the "insert" itself.  It is in the queries used to create the data (the `select` part of the `insert`).  To fix this, consider the following.

Make sure that the `id` column in `#table1` has an index:

```
create index on #table1(id);
```

And make sure that `#table2(shipment)` has an index:

```
create index on #table2(shipment);
```

Comment: Not sure if I agree with you gordon (thats a first on this forum :) )...it will help, but I think the issue is the repetition. without including the insert...He's doing 8 select statements per record... * 2 million records = 16 million select statements.

Comment: @Twelfth . . . Maybe I said it wrong.  I meant to say the "insert"s don't matter in the `insert` statement.  The issue is the performance of the `select` part.  Combining the inserts into one statement won't make a difference -- 8 versus 1 is not important.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your answer has helped bigtime! Got the same 30,000 rows from `#Table1` to `#Table2` done in 9 minutes instead of the previous 30 (I also implemented @Twelfth's comment to build the if-statement into the case/when). This `#Table1` to `#Table2` query is only a part of the query, and when I un-commented the rest, it knocked it **down** from 9 minutes to 4, any idea why? (not that I'm complaining, just seems counter-intuitive)